# Electron with Vite and Vue 3 open custom file txt

Tags: electron, vite

I added to my project folder `custom-resources`.

`custom-resources` is in the same location as the `package.json` file.

Next I add to `electron-builder.json5` file: `extraResources: ['custom-resources'],`

Now I tried to read file txt from custom-resources folder. So I added:

Function to create path:

```js
export const MCRA_RESOURCES_PATH = IS_DEV ? __dirname : process.resourcesPath
export const MCRA_RESOURCES_CATALOG_NAME = IS_DEV ? '../custom-resources' : 'custom-resources'
```

And function to read file:

```js
export const getFile = (file: string) => {
    return path.join(MCRA_RESOURCES_PATH, MCRA_RESOURCES_CATALOG_NAME, file)
}
```

When I build and install my application reading of file txt works correctly. But I have an problem with develop version.

In localhost I have path:

`/Users/michal/projects/exampleApp/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/custom-resources/test.txt`

And I got error 404 (Not Found). I don't have `electron.asar` in my project

How I can open file in localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change this:

```js
export const MCRA_RESOURCES_PATH = IS_DEV ? __dirname : process.resourcesPath
```

to this:

```js
const BASE_URL = import.meta.env.BASE_URL
export const MCRA_RESOURCES_PATH = IS_DEV ? BASE_URL : process.resourcesPath
```

And now address to file is: `/custom-resources/test.txt`. Works correctly.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as correct if it has fixed your problem.